# Android: show series of 80 jpeg images at 30FPS

Tags: android

I Have a series of 80 (720x1280) jpeg images in resources (want to set as repeating animation loop)

I am Trying to draw with a handler and runnable every 33ms (30 FPS)
Using a SurfaceHolder with associated canvas and using canvas.drawBitmap

canvas.drawBitmap is very fast if bitmap is preloaded into memory (loaded once, outside draw loop)
(i.e.: BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(). R.drawable. img_nnn);
But, each image as a bmp would take 3.7 M in heap and thus only 18 images would fit in heap

Is there any way to draw the 80 jpg images to a surfaceHolder continuosly at 30FPS?

Calling any BitmapFactory.decode functions in the draw() loop run too slow (70ms+) it appears.

Thank you!
Ken

Comment: You came to hardware limit :)

Comment: thanks guys; how come a movie player app can draw a HD movie easily at 30 FPS, but I cant draw 80 jpgs that fast, haha...

Comment: Movies are streamed off the storage if too large and not loaded into memory, also it takes less space to store the <3s movie then 80 individual jpepgs. There is a a lot of a repeated info that gets compressed in a video compared to individual frames.

Comment: thanks draksia; good info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I Have a series of 80 (720x1280) jpeg images

I don't think you can do that with `BitmapFactory`.

I know you can at least 3 options:

- create animated gif
- create wmv file and play it (more appropriate)
- use OpneGL (GL10) ES for Android that has good performance. In that case you need to learn "how to"

Comment: Maxim, thanks.  For #2 option, I thought wav file is audio only?

Comment: For Android it would be best to use mp4 container and H.264AVC for the codec, see http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: @draksia you can encode with h264 everything, btw, for most Tablets that do not support neon, you cant use h264, mpeg instead, but this is not question scope :). for sure he can use everything for video, since he wants HD720p, video file size is importent